# setting the text in ListView of fragment to right side in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement Facebook (both side) swipe with ListView on each side fragment.

I'm using below project :
https://github.com/srikanthgr/FacebookSlideOutmenu

i implemented the listView but the problem is that on right fragment the list item names are not visible (as item name start from left side by default). if i give a lot of space prior the name of item it becoms visble. 
ex: "           iphone"

the first item has a name but it aint visible.
below is code of fragment.

//Right Menu

```
public class RightMenuFragment extends ListFragment {

     @Override
      public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "                    iPhone", "                    WindowsMobile",
            " Blackberry", " WebOS", " Ubuntu", " Windows7", " Max OS X",
            " Linux", " OS/2" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);        

      }

     @Override
      public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Do something with the data
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

}
```

whereas left side works proper.

why this is happening..?
please help. thank you.

the xml layout is

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: show us the layout xml used.... i feel thats where the problem lies... to be precise,, in the view gravity

Comment: but it aint using any layout as u can see in the above code. still i'm able to get the list view , only thing its item name are not visible.

Comment: @kaps please insert your row that listview use it

Comment: @kaps  android:layout_gravity="right" not make your text to right side.Are you Know it?

Comment: @MM-BB sorry didnt get you..btw its not a customized list view, my row contains array elements.

Comment: @  kaps Ok. why you dont use customized listview. it is very easy. you can in customized listView define that a textview will start from right or left

Comment: @MM-BB but how does it would solve my issue, even though i use customized listview , it wont show my full list view.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with your specific problem, seems like the TextVIew is only half shown.

By the way for that UI pattern has recently been released the [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html).

you should definitely check it out.

Comment: no i dont wanna use DrawerLayout, i gave the link of the project which I'm modifying. if u can achieve wat i'm trying,it wud be great help.